# Editing Google Store Locator to Display Results on Separate Page (geocode function not running)

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I'm using the Google Store Locator and have set up a successful example of it where it displays the results on the same page (the standard set up with the search bar above or to the left of the map). I'm using the PHP/MySQL example and followed the instructions there:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

It works fine but now I want to take it and split it into two pages. Basically the first page would have a search form and then the second page would show the results. I am planning on using GET variables that would then be passed into the existing Javascript as PHP variables.

I took a look at this article and saw someone who was doing something similar to me but it doesn't have a link to their source code and it appears that they may have used an older version of the store locator since the JS file names aren't matching, etc. It's a good start though and it's the same approach I've been trying to use (unsuccessfully at this point):

http://magnusfive.com/forums/2011/10/store-locator-plugin-place-a-statezip-code-form-on-another-page/

I've got my example set up here:

http://miller-media.com/sites/newmaptest/results-test.php?zip_code=94546&radius=200

If you look in the original Javascript you'll see all the functions that go to work on that page (you can see them in the source code of that page as well). I'm basically needing to alter the function that gets called when someone clicks the submit button on the original page. I need run those functions on page load instead this time since it's on a new page. The original functions that run on the click look like this (btw the body element has an onload="load()" as an attribute so that's where everything starts) :

```
function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };

  document.onload = searchLocations();
}

function searchLocations() {
 var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   console.log('test');
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}

function clearLocations() {
 infoWindow.close();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
 }
 markers.length = 0;

 locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.value = "none";
 option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
 locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
 clearLocations(); 

 var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
 var searchUrl = 'test.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
     var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createOption(name, distance, i);
     createMarker(latlng, name, address);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
   locationSelect.onchange = function() {
     var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
   };
  });
}
```

Obviously the lines that need to be edited are ones that use Javascript to draw values from the page itself when someone submits the form. I've changed this line:

```
var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
```

to

```
var address = <?php echo $zip_code; ?>;
```

After declaring the variable from the GET variable. And then I changed this line:

```
var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
```

To

```
var radius = <?php echo $radius; ?>;
```

After declaring that variable. When I look at the source code, it looks fine so it appears to work correctly. I've then tried to debug by printing to the console in different parts of the code and it looks like where the code gets hung up is on this line:

```
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
```

It doesn't run the function. When I print to the console before this line, it's fine and after it does not print. So for some reason that function is not working. When I write 'geocoder' out to the console write before it, it returns:

```
Yg {geocode: function}
```

I think I can do a good job of debugging once I figure out what's causing this to get hung up. Any ideas on why the geocode() function would not run? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug in Firefox gives me error on your page:

```
uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: in property address: 94546
```

Seems odd, I know, but googles Geocoder expects a string for the 'address' parameter you pass to it, so I think I'd recommend something like:

```
var address = '<php? echo $zip_code; ?>';
```

Also, was just wondering why do you do:

```
  document.onload = searchLocations();
```

?? searchLocations does not return a value (so it assigns undefined to document.onload), and you are invoking it there so is basically same as just doing:

```
searchLocations();
```

Also, was just wondering if it's really necessary for you to even handle the address and such via php when you could just parse the current url with javascript.

Comment: Perfect, it was just a matter of making the variables strings. Thanks for your help! Just an FYI, the document.onload = searchLocations() is used to trigger that function on page load. load() is being called on page load and I need it to then call searchLocations as well. And as for the PHP variables instead of Javascript, no idea, I guess it's just a preference :)